# Windows 8.1 doesn't save wi-fi profile

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Every time, i turn on my windows machine, i have to connect to my Wifi network manually.

The WI-FI profile doesn't get saved automatically.

As per Microsoft, windows stores the WI-FI profile when you connect to a network, however in my case, it doesn't seem to happen.

I found commands on net which can help in deleting existing profiles or editing new profiles, but not for creating new profiles.

As per Google, there are many threads where in the problem existed in windows 8 but not in 8.1. But in my case, i am facing the issue in 8.1. Any suggestions how this to be fixed.

Comment: Open `cmd` and type `netsh wlan show profiles` then press enter to show all saved profiles. If your wifi isn't listed then this is proof the profile isn't being saved. If it is listed then there is a problem elsewhere. Do you have to keep entering the passphrase?

Answer (score 0):

Showing profiles doesn't work. Becuase there aren't any saved profiles.

Some how, the problem seems to be resolved. At least it worked only once. the machine connected to WI FI Automatically. The solution i tried is to put Air plane mode on. I don't understand how this worked. And am not sure whether it would work again or not. But, now it worked.